# why a 2-dimensional vector of auto_ptr in C++ does not work?

Tags: c++, c++11

I am working on a 2-dimensional vector (vector of vector) to carry some pointers in C++.

`std::vector< std::vector<object*> > data;`

here object is a class and each entry of data carries a pointer to an object instance. I make it work in C++ but the memory management makes it hard to maintain when I apply it to other code. I did some research and someone suggests using a smart pointer instead. I try the following code

```
  #include <vector>
  #include <memory>
  using namespace std;
  
  int main(void) {
    vector< int > source = {1,2,3,4,5};
    vector< auto_ptr<int> > co;
    vector< vector< auto_ptr<int> > > all;

    co.push_back( auto_ptr<int>(&source[0]) );
    co.push_back( auto_ptr<int>(&source[2]) );
    co.push_back( auto_ptr<int>(&source[4]) ); // it works well up to here

    all.push_back(co); // but it crashs here
    return 0;
  }
```

One of the error messages is

C:/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/9.2.0/bits/stl_construct.h:75:7: error: no matching function for call to 'std::auto_ptr::auto_ptr(const std::auto_ptr&)'
75 |     { ::new(static_cast<void*>(__p)) _T1(std::forward<_Args>(__args)...); }
|       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

I wonder in what way I could add the `vector< auto_ptr<int> >` to another vector or list?

Comment: Use `unique_ptr`, not `auto_ptr`. It's a remnant from before the language had the concept of moving. (Technically *was* a remnant since it's been removed now.)

Comment: _"memory management makes it hard to maintain when I apply it to other code"_ - so what is your actual problem? Maybe there are better ways to approach it.

Comment: Also note that there will be problems at runtime, when the destructor of `auto_ptr` will try to delete `source[0]`, `source[2]`, etc. You should only initialize `auto_ptr` with a pointer that was allocated individually.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, don't use `std::auto_ptr`. As you've found out, it cannot be used as an element of a vector, because it doesn't have an appropriate copy constructor. It has been deprecated since C++11 in favour of using `std::unique_ptr` instead. `std::auto_ptr` was removed from the language in C++17.

Second, objects pointed by `&source[i]` are owned by `source`. The objects aren't owned by the raw pointer that results from that expression, and there isn't even a way to transfer their ownership. As such, you mustn't give their ownership to a smart pointer. If you do, the behaviour of the program will be undefined as soon as those smart pointers are destroyed.

If you want to have a vector of vectors of smart pointers, here is a correct example:

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<int>> co;
std::vector<std::vector<std::unique_ptr<int>>> all;
for (auto i : source) {
    co.push_back(std::make_unique<int>(i));
}
all.push_back(std::move(co));
```

---

Bonus hints:

- Unless you need to swap the rows, it is more efficient to use a single dimensional vector to represent a 2 dimensional array than to use a vector of vectors.
- Unnecessary dynamic allocation can be expensive. Given that the vector elements themselves are already in dynamic storage, it is often best to store objects directly as elements instead of allocating them separately and storing smart pointers.

Comment: I am not sure if I understand unique_ptr or not. I thought each co entry carries the pointer pointing to the corresponding entry of the source, `*all[0][0].get()` does show the value of `source[0]`. However, if you change the source after all is built, `*all[0][0].get()` will not change accordingly. I wonder if `std::move` cause the problem or not, if so, does it mean unique_ptr does not really pointing to the source?

Comment: @user1285419 `does it mean unique_ptr does not really pointing to the source?` Indeed. The unique pointer has unique ownership of the object that it points to. It doesn't point to an object stored in another vector.

Answer (score 1):

`auto_ptr<T>` is something you should never use.  It has serious and unfixable design flaws.  One of them is you cannot use it in a vector.

It was depricated and removed from the C++ standard for a reason.

Use `std::unique_ptr<T>`.

Comment: Thanks. I tried unique_ptr, it works for a 1-dimensional vector, but it still fails in `vector< vector<unique_ptr> >`. I google it and seems to use shared_ptr instead work?

Comment: @user you probably need to `std::move`; errors happen because you are attempting to copy, which is barred.  Shared ptr will just hide the problem, not fix it.